# Case Feed Publisher actions missing while Creating or Editing Cases

Tags: visualforce, email, service-cloud-console, publisher-action, casefeed

I am trying to convert some of our custom VisualForce pages to use the new Case Feed functionality.  One of the main benefits is the Email Publisher action which provides many more benefits than our current solution of opening another tab to use the "/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor" Send Email page.

The problem I am facing, is that the "Case Feed" functionality (with publisher actions) doesn't seem to exist when trying to create a new or edit an existing Case.  It looks like I can add this functionality by creating my own VisualForce page using the support:caseFeed tag, and assigning it to the Edit/New Buttons, but I then lose some other functionality and it seems difficult to get it to work the way I would like it to.

Do I just have something configured wrong? Should I be able to use the email publisher actions from the "New/Edit" a case pages without having to create custom VisualForce pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable Case Feeds under Cases, support settings?

Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items

If you didn't do this - you have to go thru this process - and I would read up on it before you do.

If you have done this, and you are trying to use basic email in case feed(s) then I wish you luck.
 Because so far the implementation of email based functions in case feeds is pretty poor.

You cannot select default templates for basic things like reply, and reply all, and if you create the simplest of email publishers - the reply and reply links disappear completely.

I have spent the past 3 months hacking in this environment including creating over a dozen support cases with SFDC - if you need help post a question and I'll share with you my experience....